# Turtle graphics onkeyrelease()

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Cannot implement `onkeyrelease()` from Python's turtle module. Please advise.
Error message: `'module' object has no attribute 'onkeyrelease'`.
Tried replacing `turtle.onkeyrelease(stay, 'd')` with `wn.onkeyrelease(stay, 'd')` to no avail.

```
import turtle

speed = 0

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.tracer(0)

box = turtle.Turtle()
box.shape('square')
box.penup()

def move_right():
    global speed
    speed = 2

def stay():
    global speed
    speed = 0

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(move_right, 'd')
turtle.onkey(stay, 's')
turtle.onkeyrelease(stay, 'd')

while True:
    wn.update()
    box.setx(box.xcor() + speed)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess, based on the error message, is that you are running Python 2 and `onkeyrelease()` is a Python 3 method.  Even so:

An artifact of the transition from Python 2 to Python 3, `onkey()` and `onkeyrelease()` are *synonyms*.  What you probably want is `onkeypress()` and `onkeyrelease()`.  Even so:

That said, it's iffy whether trying to do different things on the key press and release is going to work.  On my system, *both* press and release are triggered by a key press.  Your results, due to OS perhaps, might vary.

You may be better off using two keys, 'd' to start the motion, 's' to stop it:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop

speed = 0

def move_faster():
    global speed
    speed = 2

def stay():
    global speed
    speed = 0

def move():
    box.forward(speed)
    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(move)

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

box = Turtle()
box.shape('square')
box.penup()

screen.onkey(stay, 's')
screen.onkey(move_faster, 'd')
screen.listen()

move()

mainloop()
```

This code should work under Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: Thank you for replying. What I was trying to accomplish was to move an object whilst having a key pressed, like having your foot on the accelerator. I gave up. Instead, make the mouse the controller. Use `mouseX = wn.getcanvas().winfo_pointerx()` and move the turtle left or right determined by mouseX. Maximizing the turtle Screen() helps determine mouse location. `wn` is the name of the Screen().