# 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'onkeyrelease'. Did you mean: 'onrelease'?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make my own ping pong game but it gives me this error. Whenever I try to put the onkeyrelease, this error shows up:

> 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'onkeyrelease'. Did you mean: 'onrelease'?

This is the code

```py
#imports
import random
import turtle
#turtle
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("red")
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.penup()
background = turtle.Screen()
background.bgcolor("turquoise")
bar = turtle. Turtle()
bar.shape("square")
bar.shapesize(1, 5, 1)
bar.penup()
bar.speed(100000)
bar.sety(-70)
def l():
    bar.left(50)
def r():
    bar.right()
bar.onkeyrelease(l, "Left")
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Why do you think that any such thing as `onkeyrelease` exists in the turtle module?  You probably just want `onkey`.  (The `onrelease` that your IDE is suggesting is actually related to mouse clicks, not the keyboard.)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call `onkeyrelease()` method on `Turtle` object, and it doesn't have it defined.

If you look it up in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkeyrelease), you can see that this method is called with `screen` object (in your case `background = turtle.Screen()`). It also seems that you can use `onkey()`, as these two are synonyms. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61875536/14458327) seems to confirm that.

I changed the last line in your code to `background.onkeypress(l, "Left")` and the error is gone.

Working code after small modifications:

```py
import random
import turtle

ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("red")
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.penup()

background = turtle.Screen()
background.bgcolor("turquoise")

bar = turtle.Turtle()
bar.shape("square")
bar.shapesize(1, 5, 1)
bar.penup()
bar.speed(100000)
bar.sety(-70)

def l():
    bar.left(50)

def r():
    bar.right(50)

background.onkeyrelease(l, "Left")
background.onkeyrelease(r, "Right")

turtle.listen()
background.mainloop()
```

Comment: well now it doesnt show any errors but still the arrows dont do anything

Comment: @ItzMeNick, you have to add `turtle.listen()` line at the end for the controls to be registered. Also, I needed to add `background.mainloop()` after it, so the window doesn't disappear automatically when all commands are executed. I added working code in my response

Comment: thank you sooo much :D

Comment: @ItzMeNick, you're welcome ;] You can accept my answer to mark your question as resolved